# Could not resolve COM.ANDROID.SUPPORT:DESIGN:23.0.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

During a `gradle clean build` today, I encountered this, not sure what I updated. Looks like an uppercase, lowercase mismatch. Anyone got a tip to resolve it? thanks
    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not resolve COM.ANDROID.SUPPORT:DESIGN:23.0.0.
>            Required by:
>                funride-android:app:unspecified
>   Could not resolve COM.ANDROID.SUPPORT:DESIGN:23.0.0.
>   inconsistent module metadata found. Descriptor: com.android.support:design:23.0.0 Errors: bad group: expected='COM.ANDROID.SUPPORT' found='com.android.support'
>                  bad module name: expected='DESIGN' found='design'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dependencies should look something like this

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

In build.gradle, add `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'` in the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies should be lowercase.

Also your not using the latest version of the support library you may want to update.

```
Errors: bad group: expected='COM.ANDROID.SUPPORT' found='com.android.support' bad module name: expected='DESIGN' found='design'
```

This error say we were looking for `COM.ANDROID.SUPPORT` but the only thing we found was `com.android.support`